# how to update gem command in ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

my gem version is 1.3.5 and I can't install certain gems because of that.I tried to update the gem on my computer by

```
sudo update --system
```

and it gives me an error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
gem update --system is disabled on Debian. 
RubyGems can be updated using the official     
Debian repositories by aptitude or apt-get.
```

so according to some people, the source need to be downloads and it needs to executed by ruby. i downloaded the file, did

```
sudo ruby setup.rb
```

and it gave me

RubyGems 1.8.24 installed

== 1.8.24 / 2012-04-27

- 1 bug fix:

  - Install the .pem files properly. Fixes #320
  - Remove OpenSSL dependency from the http code path

---

RubyGems installed the following executables:
    /usr/bin/gem1.8

but when I hit ruby gem -v it still gives me 1.3.5 rather than the one I installed which is 1.8.

Do I need to uninstall the older version manually? or some other thing I need to do first?

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was incorrect, but I still wanted to keep my side note: It might be worth trying out [RVM](https://rvm.io), when you have some spare time, to manage Ruby instead of the package manager. But that is somewhat beyond the scope of this question!

Comment: yeah thanks for the suggestion man, I already have that on my list to learn. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> RubyGems installed the following executables: `/usr/bin/gem1.8`

As the line says, the name of the program is `gem1.8`, not `gem`. Ergo, you need to call

```
gem1.8 -v
```

not

```
gem -v
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try make a symbolic link.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gem1.8 /usr/bin/gem
```

Comment: hi bro, i did that, then I tried to execute setup.rb but it still give me the same error but anyway thanks for the suggestion :D

Comment: in My environment.Two executable gem exisit at `/usr/bin`. One `/usr/bin/gem`, other `/usr/bin/gem1.9.1`. I tried `/usr/bin/gem1.9.1 -v` then it was `1.6.2`. Maybe, gemX.X indicate Ruby Version. Try `gem environment`. What is "RUBYGEMS VERSION"?